# Migrate TFS/DevOps Server to Azure DevOps Services into existing Organisation?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-devops-server-2020, azure-devops-services

Is it possible to migrate TFS/DevOps Server to an existing DevOps Service that already includes projects?

If it’s not possible, is there a way to manually migrate TFS repository to DevOps Services and convert the version control system to git while retaining history?

**Solution:**
I found [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) works great in migrating TFVC repositories to DevOps while also converting it to git.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't merge server collections into an existing org.

You can [migrate the TFVC repo to git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-from-tfvc?view=azure-devops) and then change the git repo's remote to Azure DevOps Service and push its entire history to only "migrate" repo's.